# Replacing NA's with values from another row, conditional on a specific country and years

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a data.table with currencies (let's say in USD) as follows, which has NA's after the country has switched to EUR. In addition, I have the year in which the currency switches to EUR:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
    "Val iso   year   
     2   NLD   1998
     NA  NLD   1999   
     NA  NLD   2000
     NA  NLD   2001   
     NA  NLD   2002  
     1   GBR   1998
     1   GBR   1999   
     2   GBR   2000
     NA  GBR   2001   
     1   GBR   2002  
     NA  EUR   1998
     1   EUR   1999   
     1   EUR   2000
     2   EUR   2001   
     1   EUR   2002  
     3   GRC   1998
     NA  GRC   1999
     4   GRC   2000
     NA  GRC   2001
     NA  GRC   2002",
   header = TRUE
)

EUR <- fread(
    " e_iso e_year   
      NLD   1999   
      GRC   2001",
   header = TRUE
)
```

I would like to use the EUR currency to replace the NA's ONLY after the respective country has switched to EUR. So, for example `Val` for `GRE` in `1999` should remain NA.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
DT[EUR$e_iso %in% DT_iso & EUR$e_year %in% DT$year, Val := ?]
```

But I am not sure how to proceed. Desired Output:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
    "Val iso   year   
     2   NLD   1998
     1   NLD   1999   
     1   NLD   2000
     1   NLD   2001   
     1   NLD   2002  
     1   GBR   1998
     1   GBR   1999   
     2   GBR   2000
     NA  GBR   2001   
     1   GBR   2002  
     NA  EUR   1998
     1   EUR   1999   
     1   EUR   2000
     2   EUR   2001   
     1   EUR   2002  
     3   GRC   1998
     NA  GRC   1999
     4   GRC   2000
     2   GRC   2001
     1   GRC   2002",
   header = TRUE
)
```

EDIT:

I made a small mistake in the desired output (which is now corrected). The value for greece in 2001 is now 2.

With for example `DT[is.na(Val), Val := EUR[.SD, as.integer(NA ^ is.na(x.e_iso)), on = .(e_iso = iso, e_year <= year)]]` line 19 is `Val` = `1` but should be `Val` = `2` since the value of the EUR in 2001 (line 14) is 2.

Comment: Could do something like `DT[is.na(Val), Val := EUR[.SD, as.integer(NA ^ is.na(x.e_iso)), on = .(e_iso = iso, e_year <= year)]]`

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidArenburg. When I run your code on my actual data I get the error: `Error in set(i, j = lc, value = as.character(i[[lc]])) : 
  .SD is locked. Updating .SD by reference using := or set are reserved for future use. Use := in j directly. Or use copy(.SD) as a (slow) last resort, until shallow() is exported.` Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Hmm.. That's probably an old data.table version. Try replacing `.SD` with `copy(.SD)`

Comment: I have update my data.table package and it works now (without `copy(.SD)`). Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was just checking my data, and for some reason every NA is replaced with one (instead of the corresponding year of the EUR) I am trying to adapt it, but I do not really understand what the `.SD, as.integer(NA ^ is.na(x.EUR_country))` part of the code does..

Comment: Can you show an example data where it doesn't work? The `as.integer(NA ^ is.na(x.EUR_country))` part is just a math/R trick that `NA^0` will be converted to 1 while `NA^(any other number)` will remain `NA`. Try `NA^1` for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see I made a small error in the desired output. I made an edit to explain.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to respond. I guess the accepted solution is much more elegant, though this is what I came up with `DT[is.na(Val), Val := EUR[DT[iso == "EUR"], on = .(e_year <= year)][.SD, on = .(e_iso = iso, e_year = year)]$Val]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DT[EUR, 
   on = .(iso = e_iso, year >= e_year), 
   Val := DT[iso == "EUR" & year == .BY, Val], 
   by = year]

    Val iso year
 1:   2 NLD 1998
 2:   1 NLD 1999
 3:   1 NLD 2000
 4:   2 NLD 2001
 5:   1 NLD 2002
 6:   1 GBR 1998
 7:   1 GBR 1999
 8:   2 GBR 2000
 9:  NA GBR 2001
10:   1 GBR 2002
11:  NA EUR 1998
12:   1 EUR 1999
13:   1 EUR 2000
14:   2 EUR 2001
15:   1 EUR 2002
16:   3 GRC 1998
17:  NA GRC 1999
18:   4 GRC 2000
19:   2 GRC 2001
20:   1 GRC 2002
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand correctly, your answers simply sets everything that fulfills the condition to `1`. The point was however to make the value correspond with the `EUR` value of the same year. How can I adapt your code to incorporate this?

Comment: With your latest edit it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We can `left_join` `DT` and `EUR` by `iso` and `replace` the values where `year >= e_year` with equivalent `"EUR"` currency of the same year.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(DT, EUR, by = c('iso' = 'e_iso')) %>%
   mutate(Val = replace(Val, year >= e_year, 
                Val[iso == "EUR" & year == first(e_year)]))


#     Val iso    year
#   <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1     2 NLD    1998
# 2     1 NLD    1999
# 3     1 NLD    2000
# 4     1 NLD    2001
# 5     1 NLD    2002
# 6     1 GBR    1998
# 7     1 GBR    1999
# 8     2 GBR    2000
# 9    NA GBR    2001
#10     1 GBR    2002
#11    NA EUR    1998
#12     1 EUR    1999
#13     1 EUR    2000
#14     2 EUR    2001
#15     1 EUR    2002
#16     3 GRC    1998
#17    NA GRC    1999
#18     4 GRC    2000
#19     1 GRC    2001
#20     1 GRC    2002
```

Comment: I was checking the data and the code and I noticed that every value fulfilling the condition is simply replaced by 1 instead of the EUR currency of the same year. Is there anyway I can incorporate this into your solution?

Comment: @Tom shouldn't the last value be 2 as well for `GRC`, so `left_join(DT, EUR, by = c('iso' = 'e_iso')) %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate(Val = if(any(!is.na(e_year))) replace(Val, year >= e_year, 
                       .$Val[.$iso == "EUR" & .$year == first(e_year)]) else Val)` . would work ?

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your help! With your last solution (in the comments), every subsequent value is one and the same value. It is no longer one, so I'm almost there. Now I only need that value to change depending on the EUR value for that year. Like I said, at the moment it takes the EUR value of the first year for every year.